# How to simulate click on Mapbox markerLayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, leaflet, mapbox

I've got a `markerLayer.on('click', function() {...})` event connected to my Mapbox, and I'm trying to fire it whenever someone clicks on an associated table item. The table items have lat/long built-in, so they already pan to the correct marker, but it doesn't necessarily fire the onclick event. Is there a simple way to change this?

**Specific Functionality Details**: Normally clicking on the Mapbox marker would display a popup with some information about that location. Each location is displayed as a row in the table, and ideally clicking on the associated row would also display the Mapbox popup.

Comment: probably need some code to really help but have you tried using $("#myElement").trigger("click")?

Comment: Do Mapbox markers even have IDs? If so, how can I find the one I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm not even sure what a mapbox is but if it's part of the DOM you can definitely target it. If you post some HTML or example with the mapbox in it I can show you

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this...create a unique sequential id for each marker in the init loop...set it in the options when you are creating it and store in an object...like

```
mapMarkers = {};
mapMarkers[currentIndex] = L.marker([35.2,25.4],{my_seq_id:currentIndex};
markerLayer.addLayer(mapMarkers[currentIndex]);
currentIndex++;
```

and set this same sequential id as a `data-myseqid`(or whatever you want) for each table row...

Then proxy both actions(map click and table clicks) through one unified place.And you then can easily tie more handlers into this.

```
function doMapAction(id) {
    mapMarkers[id].openPopup()
    //plus whatever else you need to do after a click
}

markerLayer.on('click', function(layer) {
    doMapAction(layer.options.my_seq_id);
})
$(document).on('click','td button', function(ev) {
    doMapAction(parseInt($(ev.target).data('myseqid')));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to simulate click on Mapbox markerLayer

Note that Mapbox markers are also Leaflet markers. Therefore you can use Leaflet event methods, in particular [`markerLayer.fireEvent("click")`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-events/).

As for retrieving the correct marker to fire the event on, and possibly to simplify your algorithm, refer to snkashis' good answer.